# Run single TestNG test with maven by using testng.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng

I have defined my tests in a parametrized `testng.xml`. I use the Failsafe plugin and run my tests with `mvn verify`. The whole suite is executed.

What if I have to run only one single test from my `testng.xml` suite? I want that the parameters will be used, but I want to run only one test from the command line.

The maven parameter:

```
-Dit.test=CheckoutIT#testOrderId
```

does not work because maven runs the test directly without `testng.xml`, the parameters are not bind and the test will be ignored.

Is there a way to do it? A workaround is to create a temporary suite xml with only one test but it can't be a solution...

Best regards Robert

Comment: You want to execute the tests in the testtag of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

According to testng doc:

`The command line flags that specify what tests should be run will be ignored  if you also specify a testng.xml file, with the exception of -includedgroups and -excludedgroups, which will override all the group inclusions/exclusions found in testng.xml.`

Another solution is to add listener to your maven goal which will parse your testng.xml and get test parameters to apply them to your current test.